# How to display a table in AngularDart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

Q1. **How do I display a table in AngularDart**? I just can't seem to find any examples of this on the Internet for some reason.

I'm not familiar with either JS or Dart and I'm not sure if they're compatible or not (interchangeable).

At this point any table at all will do but eventually the one in Q2 would be nice. I can get a list to work with this code:

```
<material-list>
<material-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item.property1}}
</material-list-item>
</material-list>
```

But if I try to create a table with this code from W3schools it doesn't work.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{ item.property1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.property2 }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

By creating the list I can confirm that getting an item from items works so it seems like it's syntax or something? If you know of a tutorial that would be great!

---

Q2. While I'm asking and assuming I can eventually get this to work, does anyone know if it's possible to create tables like this in AngularDart instead of AngularJS? https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-repeat is an angularjs syntax, while ngFor is the latest angular version sytax to repeat over collection and render elements.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item.property1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.property2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

here you can find an example to create a table using **[angular-dart](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/displaying-data)**

To answer your 2nd question, you can use angular-material with ngFor to create a table

**[STACKBLITZ EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-example)**

Comment: I've been on that page and I can't see any examples of tables there.

Comment: If you can tell me how to do question 2 I will accept your answer.

Comment: ok well honestly I don't understand that code. It seems to be in typescript. I've only been doing dart and angular for 1 day and only just brushed up on js for a day before that. So I can use that code in dart? You answered the questions that it's possible so I'll accept the answer. Maybe I'll have to post another question about exactly how to do that.

Comment: you can follow this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular2_material

Comment: yeah it seems that table isn't supported yet. that was my previous conclusion. it's ok a normal table will suffice for now until they include support. I've also been to that components page.

Comment: @LppEdd I'm not sure. I only needed this for one app that I made and haven't looked at it since.

Comment: there are components for AngularDart that similar to data table, for example: https://pub.dev/packages/fo_components

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it. So soon after posting. If I change the table to be like the list it seems to work.

Like this:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item.property1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.property2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

So it was definitely a syntax thing. Still it's surprising there's no examples anywhere. Also, if someone can tell me how to build one of those tables (now I'm assuming no) then I would still accept your answer.